# General Equation for Acceleration

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Question: A drum of radius R rolls down a slope without slipping. Its axis
has acceleration **a** parallel to the slope. What is the drum’s angular
acceleration α?

To solve this question, I used the general equation for acceleration:

**a** = (r¨)**rˆ** + (r˙)(θ˙)**θˆ** + (r˙)(θ˙)**θˆ** + r(θ¨)**θˆ** − r((θ˙)^2) **rˆ**

where r is the radius, (r˙) is the derivative of r, (r¨) is the second derivative of r, (θ˙) is the angular velocity, (θ¨) is the angular acceleration and **rˆ** and **θˆ** are unit vectors.

In this example, r is a constant meaning both the first and second derivative is 0 which simplifies the equation to:

**a** = r(θ¨)**θˆ** − r((θ˙)^2)**rˆ** = r(α)**θˆ** − r(ω^2)**rˆ**

My solution leads me to have an extra term.

In the solution manual, the answer is simply:

**a** = rα which implies α = **a**/r.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use Mathjax, ....

Comment: You can embed latex by using dollar sign like \$ latex-stuff here\$

Comment: I think you are confused. I think those equations describe the motion of an object's center of mass in a polar coordinate frame. Since your object is sliding down a slope (a straight line) you probably want to be using cartesian frame. Although the barrel is circular, it does not mean you should be using a polar coordinate frame.

Comment: Your math is correct. This is a matter of terminology. You correctly get that the acceleration consists of a rotational component and a centripetal one. The problem is asking for the rotational component.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b(t)$ be the distance that the barrel has rolled at time $t$. Then $b(t) = 1/2 at^2 + v_0 t$.

At time $t$, assuming there is no slip between the barrel and the surface, the point on the barrel that is touching the surface (call it particle $p_t$) must be moving with velocity exactly negative of the barrel's velocity $v_{p_t}(t) = -b'(t) = - a t -v_0$.

Its angular velocity is $\omega_{p_t}(t) = v_{p_t}(t)/r =  (-a t - v_0)/r$.

But the angular velocity is uniform for all particles on the barrel so we can drop the $p_t$ and just write $\omega(t) = (-a t - v_0)/r$

Now just take the derivative $\omega'(t) = -a/r$ to get the angular acceleration.

Comment: Note the sign here is arbitrary / depends on convention.

Answer (score 0):

Note that angular acceleration is:
$$\alpha = \frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$$
If we define $v$ to be the velocity of the axis perpendicular to the slope, with $s$ being the distance travelled:
$$v = \frac{ds}{dt}$$
In order for an object to travel a distance $s$ while having angular velocity, without slipping, we have(r is the radius of the rolling object):
$$v = \omega r$$ 
This is easy to show, and proof can be found at: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rotq.html , however this is not being asked here, so it won't be proven by me. Obviously, then we have:
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = a = r \frac{d\omega}{dt} = r\alpha $$